# stage changes in git based on regex

Tags: git

A lot of my debug code is wrapped in a header/footer. Usually I run a script that just removes all of it from source before I stage and commit the changes. If the debug code needs to persist a commit I'll run `git add -p` and stage the chunks individually.

My question is if it's possible to stage changes based on a regex? For example, given this snippet of javascript:

```
function littleNinja( sword ) {
    /* debug:start */
    console.log( sword );
    /* debug:stop */
    // do stuff
}
```

I don't want git to stage the lines between and including `debug:start` and `debug:stop`, and my hope is that this process could be automated.

Comment: That's not possible. Even if it were, sometimes the debug chunk would be inseparable from another chunk which you do want staged. You need a custom script that would handle this situation for you, or delegate the choice to you interactively. Then maybe alias the script as a git command.

Comment: Figured that was the case, but wanted to double check. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good way of doing this is to use [clean and smudge filters](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html#keyword_expansion) to filter out the marked lines as they are staged.  (The description below is essentially the same as the procedure described in that section of "Pro Git", and which is very similar to that in the [git attributes](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitattributes.html) documentation.)  First of all, we need a command that removes the lines between (and including) each `debug:start` and `debug:end` — fortunately, this is a simple job with `sed`:

```
sed '/debug:start/,/debug:stop/d' < foo.js
```

Now create a `.gitattributes` file in the top level of your git repository which contains the following line:

```
*.js filter=strip-debug
```

And now define what the `strip-debug` filter does both when 'cleaning' (on staging) or 'smudging' (on checkout):

```
git config filter.strip-debug.clean "sed '/debug:start/,/debug:stop/d'"
git config filter.strip-debug.smudge cat
```

I've (very briefly) tested this and it seems to do what you want.

Comment: Both links seem to be not found currently.